# Turning all LEDs on (FAST.LED)

Tags: arduino-nano, adafruit

In Fast.Led lib for arduino there is a code to turn off all leds

```
FastLED.clear ();
```

Is there also a shortcut to turn all LEDs ON, and with a specific color

Comment: What leds/driver are you using?

Comment: Arduino nano, FastLed lib and WS2812B leds

Comment: I think you could use [`showColor`](http://fastled.io/docs/3.1/class_c_fast_l_e_d.html#a570df74cf09e6215c3647333d2b479a9)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use fill_solid.

For example

```
fill_solid( leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB(50,0,200));
```

Or

```
fill_solid( leds, NUM_LEDS, CRGB::Red);
```

Comment: Works fine. While **FastLED.showColor()** will not behave properly if you add delay after it,